# Inserting an array type object in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to add an object array into my database using mongoDB shell. I get an `"SyntaxError: Unexpected String"` error.

**Code**:

```
db.Tests.insert(
    {
        "id": "chapter1"
        "questions": [
            {
                "questionID": "1",
                "question": "How much is 1+1",
                "Answer1": "1",
                "Answer2": "2",
                "Answer3": "3",
                "Answer4": "4",
                "CorrectAns": "2"
            } 
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: You missed a comma after the `"id": "chapter1"` key-value

Comment: Thank you very much. That seemed to be the problem. Kind regards and all the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Tests.insert(
    {
        "id": "chapter1", // <=== here is the bug
        "questions": [
            {
                "questionID": "1",
                "question": "How much is 1+1",
                "Answer1": "1",
                "Answer2": "2",
                "Answer3": "3",
                "Answer4": "4",
                "CorrectAns": "2"
            } 
        ]
    }
)
```